# Where do you share or find useful powershell, bash, batch, vbs, scripts?

Tags: bash, powershell, open-source, share, scripting

I just wrote a quick little powershell script to make my life easier for a task that I was facing. I thought it would be nice to put it on the Internet, where someone else may also find it useful. The trouble is that it feels like overkill to open a new CodePlex or SourceForge "PROJECT" for my little script.

Is there an similar site for sharing or open-soucing scripts?

Comment: Although I think this question is [Good Subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/), you may still consider marking it as CW.  I don't know if there is a single, most correct answer.  Also, +1.

Comment: Admin feel free to make it wiki question...

Comment: *waves hammer* Done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Github](https://github.com/) is commonly used for this sort of thing as is [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/).

Comment: [Gist](https://gist.github.com/) is a git-backed paste-bin.

Answer (score 5):

There are several powershell repositories:
http://poshcode.org/

The TechNet script center:
http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/ScriptCenter/

You may get better exposure there since the audience is powershell focused

Comment: I'd add the [Hey, Scripting Guy! blog](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/) can also be useful.

Comment: as a source, I agree.  To post your own, the ScriptCenter is their repository